# Can I use configparser to make a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, configparser

Currently, I am using configparser to make a dictionary of Person-class objects from a .ini file, which looks like this (in the real dictionary, there are many more people):

```
[Pers1]
name = Alice
sex = female

[Pers2]
name = Bob
sex = male
```

This parsed dictionary is called `people`, so `people['Pers1'].name` is the `name` attribute of `Pers1`, `"Alice"`. `people['Pers2'].sex` is `"male"`, and so on.

Now, let's say I want Alice to have another attribute, called `tags`. `tags` would be a dictionary, with a structure like this:

```
people['Pers1'].tags = {
'Employed':
    {COMPANY: 'Macrosoft',
     EMPLOYEE_SINCE: '1/5/2005'
     },
'LicensedPilot':
    {LICENSE_ISSUED: '6/7/2007',
     EXPIRATION_DATE: '12/11/2017'
     }
}
```

`tags` is a dictionary that may be empty, or may contain more dictionaries (though only nested one-deep, so no dictionaries-of-dictionaries-of-dictionaries... in `tags`).

Is there a way to set up configparser to read a .ini and create these dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INI by itself is a flat format. If you want to store nested data in it, you will need to handle that.

For example, qualified property names:

```
[Pers1]
name = Alice
sex = female
tags.COMPANY = Macrosoft
tags.EMPLOYEE_SINCE = 1/5/2005
```

Note, these will still be returned as a 'flat' `options` list, e.g. the first tag will have a key of `"tags.COMPANY"`. You would need split the option names on `.` and handle the results yourself.

Another approach would be to use a format that is meant to store nested data and be translated directly to lists and dictionaries, such as YAML.